# Is possible to extract the text of an element compared with the end of the value of an attribute of current node?

Tags: xpath, xpath-1.0

I have an XML like this

```
<Values>
    <Value ID="Contents01" Name="Contents 01" QualifierID="en-US">
        <Text>It is a test [{placeHolder01}]</Text>
    </Value>
    <Value ID="VarPlaceHolderValue01" Name="Var Place Holder 01" QualifierID="en-US">[{placeHolder01}]</Value>
    <Value ID="Contents02" Name="Contents 02" QualifierID="en-US">
        <Text>Some extra text.</Text></Value>
    <Value ID="PlaceHolder01" Name="PlaceHolder 01" QualifierID="en-US">
        <Text>For StackOverflow</Text>
    </Value>
</Values>
```

Would be possible to get with an expression the QualifierID of the PlaceHolderValue01, having the currently selected node the PlaceHolder01.
So the idea would be something like this from an already selected node.

```
//Values/Value[starts-with(@ID,'Var') and substring(./@ID, string-length(./@ID) - 2) = substring(@ID, string-length(@ID) - 2)]/text()
```

However I am getting syntax error with the xpath checkers, how it should work correctly?

Is it possible to do this with only xpath? The idea is to extract the text of the element VarPlaceHolderValue01, knowing that starts with Var and ends with the same number value of the current selected node?

Comment: You have a closing </Value> tag missing for 'Contents02' and you have an extra '/' after the Value node in your XPath expression (should be //Values/Value[...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying it out in iPython:

First, to select the node:

```
In [11]: root.xpath('//Value[starts-with(@ID, "PlaceHolder")]')
Out[11]: [<Element Value at 0x1094a1a00>]
```

Next, to isolate the string to be matched:

```
In [13]: root.xpath('substring-after(//Value[starts-with(@ID, "PlaceHolder")]/@ID, "PlaceHolder")')
Out[13]: '01'
```

Next, to match the "Var"-starting element and extract its text.

```
In [18]: root.xpath('string(//Value[starts-with(@ID, "Var") and  contains(@ID, substring-after(//Value[starts-with(@ID, "PlaceHolder")]/@ID, "PlaceHolder"))])')
Out[18]: '[{placeHolder01}]'
```

Comment: I've been testing it and works, however if there are more items with ID starting with PlaceHolder it does not work as expected. As it detects the first one, instead the value of the current node. If we have PlaceHolder01 and PlaceHolder02 for PlaceHolder02 it detects as well PlaceHolder01

Comment: For this, you will have to write an xpath that selects the "current node" and replace `//Value[starts-with(@ID, "PlaceHolder")]` with it in the last example. What that will be will depend on your input XML.